# conversion to '__uint8_t' from '__uint32_t' may alter its value in Eclipse

Tags: c++

I get a problem when i trying to add the `__stm32cube lib__` to my **eclipse** project.

```
#define __HAL_RCC_HSE_CONFIG(__STATE__) (*(__IO uint8_t *)RCC_CR_BYTE2_ADDRESS = (__STATE__))
```

There is a error for this definition says

```
 __conversion to '__uint8_t' from '__uint32_t' may alter its value__
```

.

I tried to add an `_int8_t` but still show up this error. Any one knows how to solve this problem?

There is a predefine `__define RCC_CR_BYTE2_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t)0x40023802)__`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: uint32_t can hold bigger values than a uint8_t, so did you try to use a uint32_t instead of uint8_t?

Comment: Hey, thanks your reply. I actually didnot change anything in this lib before this error shows up, I now will try to change it to uint32_t and have a try.

Comment: `__STATE__` value appears to be `uint32_t`. Basically what code in question does is saves given `__STATE__` into one byte at specified address, and compiler says that source data may be larger than one byte. Blindly changing pointer from `uint8_t` to `uint32_t` isn't really good idea as it may stomp memory. If values of `__STATE__` always fits one byte - cast it to `uint8_t` (`(*(__IO uint8_t *)RCC_CR_BYTE2_ADDRESS = (uint8_t)(__STATE__))`)

Comment: Yep, This should be a better method. Thanks.